# Index view loading very slowly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, caching, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model Schools and a model PerformanceStats.

```
PerformanceStat 
belongs_to :school

School
has_one :performance_stat
```

the index page for PerformanceStat shows all 2,000 performance stats, and also the school.name, school.score, and school.city, and I need access to the school.id and school.slug.

Controller:

```
def index
   @performance_stats=PerformanceStat.all
end
```

My view code:

```
 <tbody>
 <% @performance_stats.each do |stat| %>
   <% school = School.find(stat.school_id)%>
    <tr>
      <td><%= link_to school.name, school_path(city: school.city.parameterize.truncate(80, omission: ''), slug: school.slug) %></td>
     <td><%= number_with_precision(school.score, precision: 2)%></td>
```

then the view goes on to display the performance stats.

This view load very slowly....10-20 seconds.  How can I speed things up?  I've tried PerformanceStats.scoped, and plucking school stats and selecting from an array, but these don't seem to help. Is there a way for me to access the school attributes without finding a School for every PerformanceStat?  I believe the School.find bit is slowing things down considerably.

I have indexes on :school_id in PerformanceStat, and :score, :slug in the School model.

UPDATE:

The suggestion in the selected answer to add a cache resulted in this line of code in the index action of the SchoolsController:

```
fresh_when etag: @performance_stats
```

The load time dropped to 18ms.  This solution works great for me because the content of the index action does not change often.  This data gets updated once a year. [This link](https://medium.com/rubyinside/https-medium-com-wintermeyer-caching-in-ruby-on-rails-5-2-d72e1ddf848c) has other suggested cache solutions for data that changes frequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PerformanceStat.all` is a heavy query if you've a lot of data in this table and it'll be finding school for each `performance stat`. 
What I can understand from your code is that you're facing (N + 1) problem over here.

**NOTE**: you should not fire queries from your views or helpers and let the controller do all the action.

For instance in your code:

```
<% @performance_stats.each do |stat| %>
   <% school = School.find(stat.school_id)%> <- #THIS IS WRONG & LET THE ASSOCIATIONS DO ALL THE ACTION ON ITS OWN
     <tr>
       <td><%= link_to school.name, school_path(city: school.city.parameterize.truncate(80, omission: ''), slug: school.slug) %></td>
       <td><%= number_with_precision(school.score, precision: 2)%></td>
```

you can use `includes`, `PerformanceStat.includes(:school)` it will fetch all the schools for each PerformanceStat.

your controller code should be:

`@performance_stats = PerformanceStat.includes(:school)`

instead of : `@performance_stats = PerformanceStat.all`

and your view code will now be:

```
<% @performance_stats.each do |stat| %>
   <% school = stat.school %> #make sure all stats have a school assigned to them otherwise you can put a check below whether the school is nil or not
     <tr>
       <td><%= link_to school.name, school_path(city: school.city.parameterize.truncate(80, omission: ''), slug: school.slug) %></td>
       <td><%= number_with_precision(school.score, precision: 2)%></td>
```

Comment: Thanks, this change reduced the load time to 4-5 seconds.  Still kind of long, but much better!

Comment: you can decrease the time by selecting only the columns which you need and also by pagination as well. 
caching can also be done and this will be the best solution to optimise it.

Comment: Wow, this one simple line in my index controller action has reduced load time to 18ms!!     'fresh_when etag: @performance_stats'

Comment: This is something new I learnt from your comment today! Thanks and congratulations!

Answer (score 1):

Quite a few things here. First of all change your controller method to this one, otherwise you will run into n+1 queries

```
def index
 @performance_stats=PerformanceStat.includes(:school)
end
```

Since you have eagerly loaded the school, now you can access it directly in your view as

```
<% stat.school %>
```

Secondly loading almost 2000 records in one go is not optimal at all, it's gonna take a while to load all records. For this you must add pagination by using following gems

- [kaminari](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari)
- [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate)